# Why is @channel disabled in Slack threads?

Tags: notifications, slack

When using Slack I frequently run to the situation when something important comes up in the thread and I need to notify everyone on the channel about that.
But this dialog appears – **Disabled in threads:**

[image: slack message - disabled in threads]

---

So. Now I use two features – I write the message to thread with selecting the checkbox `Also send to [#channel]` and I notify everyone in the channel by writing directly to the channel something like `@channel :uparrow:`.

But it seems like an unnecessary complication to me. Maybe it is just disabled somewhere in settings, but I didn't find it there.
So the questions are:

**Why is @channel disable in Slack thread?**
and.
**Can I enable it somehow as a workspace owner?**

Answer (score 1):

No, you can’t tag the channel in a thread. If you think it’s an important feature, you should provide feedback to Slack directly.

[Slack - Threads](https://slack.com/help/articles/115000769927-Use-threads-to-organize-discussions-):

> Using an @here or @channel mention in a thread won’t notify members in the conversation.

Your current method seems like a good option. You could also create a new post that nicely summarizes the context/action required etc with a link to a message from the thread (more as a reference).

Comment: ok thanks, do you have any clue why it is disabled? I don't see any good reason for that…

Comment: I think it's more straightforward to keep `@channel` out of a thread. That creates a new place to discuss the message, instead of getting lost in the original discussion. I'm also against using `@here/@channel` unless it's urgent - but I know not everyone feels that way.

Comment: @TGar I also noticed that when I mute a channel and get an `@channel` notification, I have to manually find the message. This would be harder if I had to dig into threads.

Answer (score 1):

I found that when a comment with an @channel mention is edited, if we redo the @channel mention, it will send out a notification.

Here I am editing an existing reply inside a thread.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way!

At least in Windows client there is setting on a channel:

Context menu -> Change notifications -> Get notified about all replies and show them in your Threads view

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).